# Install a python package with an ext_module depending on third party library

Tags: python, pip, pypi, re2

I want to install a python package via pip (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/re2/), but this package contains a extension_module which depends on the re2 library (https://github.com/google/re2).

When i want to install the package, i have to compile and install the re2 library before or the `pip install re2` command fails.
Because of restrictions on the build system I cannot simply install re2 on the production machines before running pip, but i would need to integrate the compilation and installation of the library into pip somehow.

So are there any possibilities to compile and install third party c libraries in the setup.py of a python package?

Answer (score 0):

There are Python bindings [here](https://github.com/facebook/pyre2/). Just run `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Seems to me like it has the same problem, the compilation of the included _re2.cc file fails

Comment: It looks like you need some Makefile or C compiler?